# Excel combo box - How do you use the tab key to select a cell?

Tags: excel, combobox, tabs

I am using a combo box in Excel. Is there a way that I can use the tab key to select a specific cell when I am in the combo box? For example if I just selected something from the dropdown list or typed it in, can I somehow press the tab key to select the next field that would need to be filled in? This is the only object on the spreadsheet, so the next item I would want to select is a cell. When I press the tab key I can’t get it to do anything.

This tidbit of information probably will not be of any use, but I am using VB script to populate the combo box. The script works great so I don’t need help with that. The tab thing will not work if it is a new combo box without script either. I thought I would mention this because I would be willing to use some sort of script in order to get the tab key to work.

I am using Office 2010 and Windows 7, if this information is needed.

Thanks for any help someone can provide.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to get this to work! Here it is, in case someone else should find this useful. My combo box is called cboSites. You can also add additional If statement under the KeyDown sub to get it to do different stuff. Like if you want to use the enter key instead do a or statement with the value of 13 instead of 9. You can do any key on the keyboard this way.

```
Private Sub cboSites_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

If KeyCode = 9 Then
    Range("B5").Select
End If

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Range("B4"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    ActiveSheet.cboSites.Activate
End If

End Sub
```